# No module named flask in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, module, flask

When I run a new (Fresh creation without any modifications) Flask Web Project in Visual Studio it does not compile. I get an error "No module named flask". This makes no sense to me because it was a "Flask" project that I created and I didn't do anything to break it. Is it possible that Microsoft provides broken template for new  Flask projects? I'm confused.

When I try to add a virtual environment I get the following log:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: valueInstalling 'pip' package manager.
Downloading setuptools from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317603
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\pip_downloader.py", line 47, in <module>
    setuptools_package, _ = urlretrieve(SETUPTOOLS_SOURCE, 'setuptools.tar.gz')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 94, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 240, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 437, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 991, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 844, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 806, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1198, in connect
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 392, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 310, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
'pip' failed to install. Exit code: 1
C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named pip
```

Comment: Take a look at [this guide](https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Flask) from Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks @dim. I tried adding a virtual environment but it wasn't working and I saw a few comments on other threads to "not" use one. I am unclear on the full ramifications of either choice so I edited my post just now to add the log results from adding a virtual environment. The conclusion that seems most obvious is that pip is not installed properly, however, I was trying to rely on MSVS to take care of all that for me since I have zero experience with Python. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

you will need to install flask as shown below using powershell in administrator mode

```
PS C:\Python34> pip install flask
Collecting flask
  Downloading Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz (544kB)
    100% |################################| 544kB 210kB/s
Collecting Werkzeug>=0.7 (from flask)
  Downloading Werkzeug-0.10.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (293kB)
    100% |################################| 294kB 28kB/s
Collecting Jinja2>=2.4 (from flask)
  Downloading Jinja2-2.7.3.tar.gz (378kB)
    100% |################################| 380kB 262kB/s
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.21 (from flask)
  Downloading itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46kB)
    100% |################################| 49kB 293kB/s
Collecting markupsafe (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask)
  Downloading MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: flask, Jinja2, itsdangerous, markupsafe
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for flask
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\TrustM\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\d2\db\61\cb9b80526b8f3ba89248ec0a29d6da1bb60136
930fca987
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Jinja2
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\TrustM\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\b3\c0\62\8908d15b90a7de8bd15e2e6e5f5ba1398c0d99
62a6bf8f5
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for itsdangerous
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\TrustM\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\97\c0\b8\b37c320ff57e15f993ba0ac98013eee778920b
b3ebae3cf
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for markupsafe
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\TrustM\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\94\a7\79\f79a998b64c1281cb99fa9bbd33cfc9b8b5775
8218d17a7
Successfully built flask Jinja2 itsdangerous markupsafe
Installing collected packages: Werkzeug, markupsafe, Jinja2, itsdangerous, flask
Successfully installed Jinja2-2.7.3 Werkzeug-0.10.4 flask-0.10.1 itsdangerous-0.24 markupsafe-0.23
PS C:\Python34> pip install django
Collecting django
  Downloading Django-1.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB)
    100% |################################| 6.2MB 15kB/s
Installing collected packages: django
Successfully installed django-1.8.2
PS C:\Python34>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Visual Studio had a banner asking if I wanted to create a virtual environment; all I had to do was agree to have Visual Studio do that for me and it fixed the issue right away.